# <input type="file" accept="application/pdf"> Does not work on chrome android

Tags: android, html, web-applications

In my webapp I have this piece of html. On my mac and I presume on any pc when I click on it I see a window where I can choose a file and only .PDF are enabled; But when I try the very same page from my android I can choose files or camera and whatever I pick I can always choose any type of file.

Is there a way to make this work on Android too ?

```
<input class="form-control" name="document_upload" type="file"
                                   accept=".pdf" required id="document_upload">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour in Chrome for Android according to caniuse:
https://caniuse.com/input-file-accept

> Offers appropriate file locations/input based on format type, but does not prevent other files from being selected.

You can add this simple validation to ensure that the user selects the correct file type via JavaScript:

```html
<input class="form-control" name="document_upload" type="file" accept=".pdf" required id="document_upload">

<script>
document.getElementById('document_upload').addEventListener('change', function() {
    const fileInput = this;
    const selectedFile = fileInput.files[0];
    
    if (selectedFile) {
        if (selectedFile.type === 'application/pdf') {
            // Valid file
        } else {
            // Invalid file
            alert('Please, select a PDF file.');
            fileInput.value = '';
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Desktops like Wimdows should not be inferior/no different in abilities to mobiles so here I can upload any file too.

[image]

I can edit /rename the filename to a .pdf and that will bypass any filename checker. and even if I check the magic header for %PDF that too can be spoofed. so the best way to tell you have a PDF uploaded is not run it, but analyse for trojan contents.